# Rails form isn't updating all fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm back with another Rails question. I have a form that is used for updating a user's profile, and part of it has a profile image for upload. I also have some cropping happening, so I am passing along some cropping information in hidden fields (crop_x, crop_y, crop_w, crop_h).

Here is what seems to be happening in the log when I submit the form:

```
Started PATCH "/talent_profiles/5" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-16 10:13:45 -0500
Processing by TalentProfilesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"JO5VpUzKofGkNtf61LlfhzR3QbhI0GYuvyX5+Ev8lky272jkc7+ZpwnyRw2wZY4AIoWZlhZGvliGfSLvmXkKsw==", "talent_profile"=>{"profile_image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fb277003198 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/4b/ft8tw3cj0fv77lg1b8mhn72r0000gn/T/RackMultipart20170816-23354-1wjo797.png>, @original_filename="Home.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"talent_profile[profile_image]\"; filename=\"Home.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">, "crop_x"=>"622.0916920162501", "crop_y"=>"2175.4168294233164", "crop_w"=>"632.2108016602303", "crop_h"=>"632.2108016602303", "first_name"=>"Bob", "last_name"=>"Bobson"}, "commit"=>"Save Changes", "id"=>"5"}
  TalentProfile Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "talent_profiles".* FROM "talent_profiles" WHERE "talent_profiles"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE "talent_profiles" SET "profile_image" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "talent_profiles"."id" = $3  [["profile_image", "Home.png"], ["updated_at", "2017-08-16 15:13:46.061927"], ["id", 5]]
   (6.1ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/talent_profiles/5
Completed 302 Found in 1064ms (ActiveRecord: 6.8ms)
```

As you can see, it is sending along the cropping information. However, on running @profile.update_attributes(talent_profile_update_params), it will never update the crop fields on the talent_profile. I have :crop_x, :crop_y, etc. added to the talent_profile_update_params like so:

```
def talent_profile_update_params
        params.require(:talent_profile).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :profile_image, :remove_profile_image, :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h)
end
```

In case this helps, here is the starting line of my form:

```
<%= form_for(@profile,:html=>{:id=>"update-profile",:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
```

Do any of you have any ideas why these fields aren't being updated, even though they are allowed in the talent_profile_update_params? I'm going a little crazy...

UPDATE: Here is my model:

```
class TalentProfile < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    mount_uploader :profile_image, ProfileImageUploader
    attr_accessor :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h
    validates :profile_image, file_size: { less_than: 5.megabytes }
    after_update :crop_profile_image

    def crop_profile_image
        if crop_x.present?
            profile_image.recreate_versions!
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Is there any code in your model / included modules in that model that could remove those `crop_*` attributes?

Comment: I've added my model to the bottom of the question. I don't think there is anything removing them, but I'm very new to Ruby/Rails so I'm not entirely sure. Thanks for the response.

Comment: You should not use `attr_accessor`. It defines getter/setter methods for new object attributes that are not stored in the database. Remove that line and you should be fine.

Comment: The problem appears to be that the new crop info isn't being passed to the uploader - so `recreate_versions!` won't actually change anything.  Can you post how the uploader determines the version sizes?  Are these crop fields supposed to be saved in the database (as @MrYoshiji is presuming)?

Comment: Thank you very much! I had that line in there from a previous tutorial and thought it was needed. Thanks for clearing that up!